# What are the differences between "__GFP_NOFAIL" and "__GFP_REPEAT"?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel

As per the documentation (https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6930),
which says:

```
Flag           Description
__GFP_REPEAT   The kernel repeats the allocation if it fails.
__GFP_NOFAIL   The kernel can repeat the allocation.
```

So, both of them may cause the kernel to repeat the allocation operation.
How can I choose between them?
What are the major differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't really "documentation", but just an article on LinuxJournal. Granted, the author (Robert Love) is surely knowledgeable on the subject, but nonetheless those descriptions are quite imprecise and outdated (the article is from 2003).

The `__GFP_REPEAT` flag was renamed to `__GFP_RETRY_MAYFAIL` in kernel version 4.13 (see [the relevant patchwork](https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/802988/)) and its semantics were also modified.

The original meaning of `__GFP_REPEAT` was (from [`include/linux/gfp.h` kernel v4.12](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.12/source/include/linux/gfp.h#L139)):

```
__GFP_REPEAT: Try hard to allocate the memory, but the allocation attempt
  _might_ fail.  This depends upon the particular VM implementation.
```

The name and semantic of this flag were somewhat unclear, and the new `__GFP_RETRY_MAYFAIL` flag has a much clearer name and description (from [`include/linux/gfp.h` kernel v5.7.2](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7.2/source/include/linux/gfp.h#L165)):

```
%__GFP_RETRY_MAYFAIL: The VM implementation will retry memory reclaim
procedures that have previously failed if there is some indication
that progress has been made else where.  It can wait for other
tasks to attempt high level approaches to freeing memory such as
compaction (which removes fragmentation) and page-out.
There is still a definite limit to the number of retries, but it is
a larger limit than with %__GFP_NORETRY.
Allocations with this flag may fail, but only when there is
genuinely little unused memory. While these allocations do not
directly trigger the OOM killer, their failure indicates that
the system is likely to need to use the OOM killer soon.  The
caller must handle failure, but can reasonably do so by failing
a higher-level request, or completing it only in a much less
efficient manner.
If the allocation does fail, and the caller is in a position to
free some non-essential memory, doing so could benefit the system
as a whole.
```

As per `__GFP_NOFAIL` you can find a detailed description [in the same file](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7.2/source/include/linux/gfp.h#L183):

```
%__GFP_NOFAIL: The VM implementation _must_ retry infinitely: the caller
cannot handle allocation failures. The allocation could block
indefinitely but will never return with failure. Testing for
failure is pointless.
New users should be evaluated carefully (and the flag should be
used only when there is no reasonable failure policy) but it is
definitely preferable to use the flag rather than opencode endless
loop around allocator.
Using this flag for costly allocations is _highly_ discouraged.
```

---

In short, the difference between `__GFP_RETRY_MAYFAIL` and `__GFP_NOFAIL` is that the former will retry allocating memory only a finite amount of times before eventually reporting failure, while the latter will keep trying indefinitely until memory is available and will never report failure to the caller, because it assumes that the caller cannot handle allocation failure.

Needless to say, the `__GFP_NOFAIL` flag must be used with care only in scenarios in which no other option is feasible. It is useful in that it avoids explicitly calling the allocator in a loop until a request succeeds (e.g. `while (!kmalloc(...));`), and thus it's more efficient.